# Process stops when one URL in file causes error

Tags: youtube-dl

I use `youtube-dl -a filename` to download the videos. However, when one URL in the list of URLs fail, the process exits, is there a way to skip the failing URL and proceeding with the remaining URLs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **man page** of **youtube-dl** says:

```
 -i, --ignore-errors             Continue on download errors, for example to skip unavailable
                                 videos in a playlist
```

Thus:

```
youtube-dl -i -a filename
```

---

**edit:** I strongly advice you to run

```
youtube-dl -U
```

prior to any download, as the world of online videos is fast changing and updates often fix download errors. Moreover, some errors are due to content restriction and can be solved by adding *login* and *password* to the tool:

```
 youtube-dl -u USERNAME -p PASSWORD
```